# When doing a reverse geocoding request Google magically recognizes my iPhone language

Tags: iphone, reverse-geocoding

Im sending a simple url request using the following url:

```
urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
             @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=true", lat, lng];
```

Let's say my current location is Europe, Romania, Oradea.

If I set my iPhone to German for example, I get the city name in german. Somehow Google magically knows that my iPhone is German and returns geocoding data in german (Grosswardein). The problem is I would **really** like to have the city name untranslated (Oradea in romanian). How does google know that my iPhone's language is German, and how do I stop this. I'm not using MKReverseGeocoder because I couldn't turn this feature off but now I'm facing the exact same problem here.

**Update**: There are no headers sent:
`[request allHTTPHeaderFields]` returns null. It seems Google is clairvoyant.

**Update**: This: `[request setValue: @"*" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept-Language"]` seems to work.
As far as I understand from [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) I should use an asterisk. BTW [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to see if your request includes `Accept-Language` HTTP headers. Dunno how you send it, but it sounds like it does.

Comment: Thanks for help, I verified the `Accept-Language` header after I created the request and it's nil. Is there a way to see all the headers sent?

Comment: @gyozo kudor: Why not use Wireshark to see the entire dialogue between your app and Google? That way you can pin down exactly what is giving it away.

Comment: Wireshark tells me that there is indeed an Accept-Language header there and it is set to `de-de`, This is after I set it to nil like this `[request setValue: nil forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept-Language"]`.

Comment: But setting the header to an empty string instead of nil works.

Comment: So it seems that if Accept-Language isn't set, Google does a geoIP lookup to guess your language. Question solved, it seems.

Comment: I changed the empty string to `*` that seems the correct way. Also updated my question to show it. Using empty string the header is still set (visible with wireshark) but probably invalid and google probably ignores it.